# How to use the keyboard in gthumb image viewer?

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, shortcut-keys, gthumb

I cannot use `arrows` nor `shift-space`, nor any key or key combination to go to previous image in gthumb 2.13.1 (Ubuntu Natty Narwhal 11.10). There should be **shortcut-keys** even to flip horizontally and vertically. And I cannot have a preview box (like before).
I think that there is no need to do image viewers that are worse and more clumsy to use than previews programs or previous versions of the same program. Hello! What is going on?

Answer (score 6):

There are still some key combinations/shortcut-keys available. [This is a nice list](http://library.gnome.org/users/gthumb/unstable/gthumb-shortcuts.html.en), but in gThumb 3.0.1 (Ubuntu 12.04) a lot of the shortcut-keys don't work (anymore). But I can still use:
<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Page down</kbd> View the next image.
<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Page up</kbd> View the previous image.
<kbd>Delete</kbd> Delete photo & will move the picture to the trash again
<kbd>+</kbd> Zoom in
<kbd>-</kbd> Zoom out
<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd> Actual size
<kbd>x</kbd> Zoom to fit (scales down only, does not magnify)
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> Zoom to fit (scale down or magnify, as required)
<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>f</kbd> Fullscreen

With gThumb 3.12+ you can **change keyboard shortcuts**: Preferences > Shortcuts.
There are **bug reports** on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gthumb/-/issues/12) and [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gthumb/+bug/474687) for this, please subscribe, comment and contribute if possible.

Not sure what you mean with preview box, the **thumbnail pane** (`F8` to close and open it) still works and you can switch it to the side if that is more convenient for you.

[image: gthumb 3.0.1 screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Page up</kbd>/<kbd>Page down</kbd> works to see the previous/next image in GTHUMB 3.0.1 (Ubuntu 12.04).

<kbd>DEL</kbd> works for me to remove the file from the viewer, but it doesn't actually delete the file from disk. Anyone knows how to view the GTHUMB trash from which I hopefully can empty it?

Comment: If you have another question, don't put it into an answer, please [ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) another question.

Comment: the deleted files get moved into your local trash folder

Answer (score 0):

Several years later, I'd simply recommend updating gThumb to the newest version (3.12), which is the first one that allows to personalise keyboard shortcuts. This way you can assign arrow keys to go to the next/previous image. It's crazy that the most important upgrade appeared in 2021.

`sudo apt upgrade gthumb`