# Simple image viewer that is using trash rather than permanently deleting files?

Tags: lubuntu, delete, lxde, trash, image-viewers

I tried `gpicview`, `nomacs`, `mirage` and `viewnior` - all are permanently deleting images (there is a prompt) rather than using trash.

I would prefer moving to trash without confirmation. Moving to trash after confirmation also would be better than not using trash.

Is it some strange design tradition of not using trash on Linux? Is it maybe some system-wide setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb), available from package with this name is able to use Ubuntu trash folder (out of the box, without changing any settings).

It is also possible to stop confirmation before moving to trash using Edit | Preferences - tag General, section Other.

[Eye of GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_GNOME) is also able to use trash and it is enabled by default, but it is impossible to pernamently disable confirmation before moving file to trash. It resides in package `eog`.

gwenview also technically fits but is unusable due to horrible effects and animations, without option for disabling them (according to http://kde-bugs-dist.kde.narkive.com/YHb61htK/bug-289213-make-crossfade-animation-optional it should be possible once Ubuntu package is updated). Also, selecting "install plugins" results in installation of programs spamming start menu.

Comment: there are some problems with shortcuts in gthumb: arrow keys dont work, but pgup/down or space/bspace do. https://askubuntu.com/questions/142632/how-to-use-the-keyboard-in-gthumb-image-viewer

Answer (score 1):

I [forked Viewnior 1.4](https://github.com/AnthonyAstige/Viewnior) to delete to trash on my Ubuntu 14.10 install.

**Other notes**

If configure yells it's missing exiv2  `sudo apt-get install libexiv2-dev` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The illusion of a "trash bin" is created by the file manager, e.g. Nautilus. It is just a normal directory somewhere in your home. For Nautilus, I think, it's `~/.local/share/Trash`. The Linux kernel itself doesn't know about the trash bin.

However, as there are quite a few file managers for Linux (I can name Nautilus, Nemo, Dolphin, Caja and PCManFM from memory, but there certainly are more than just those), it is near to impossible to create a program which moves items to the trash of the current file manager compatible with all file managers out there.

So I think you'll have a hard time finding a program fit for your needs. And if you don't find anything, you could get the source code of your favorite image display software and patch it so it will move images to PCManFM's (or another one if you don't use LXDE's default FM) trash.

Comment: Most file managers these days should be following the [freedesktop trash specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html), shouldn't they? According to that spec, `~/.local/share/Trash` is the agreed-upon trash bin location.

Comment: [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb), available from package with this name is able to use Ubuntu trash folder (out of the box, without changing any settings).

Answer (score 0):

launch the `File Manager` get into menu -> Preferences -> Behavior -> Trash where you have choices about enabling a permanent delete or simply put into the trash bucket